# Is It Possible to Point to Multiple Arrays Within Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

SO for a project I am doing, I would like to be able to create a multidimensional array which would look like:

```
private static String[][] docArray = new String[6][];
```

For that array I'd establish something like:

```
docArray[0].equals(headingValue);
.
.
.
docArray[5].equals(anotherValue);
```

Then say I want to do something like have index 3 point to a child array, logically I'd think you'd do something like the following (although I know it's not the correct syntax)...

```
docArray[3][1] = new String[6][];
```

So am I correct in my logic thus far, and how do I continue about adding pointers to new arrays? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this is that if `docArray` is a `String[][]`, then `docArray[3][1]` should be a `String`, not a `String[][]`.

What you *could* do is type `docArray` as an `Object[][]`; this would allow you to do what you want since every `String` is an `Object` and a jagged `String[][]` array is *also* an `Object`.

Comment: So instead of calling any of the arrays type String[][], could I just call them all type Object[][]? Would there be any drawbacks with that?

Comment: @This 0ne Pr0grammer: The drawback would be that you could put things in them other than `String` objects, naturally. But you could always write your own class to wrap this structure and control access to it.

Comment: SO if I have something like, `docArray[3][0] = (new Object[6][]);` how do I access that new array to store another array in it?

Comment: @This 0ne Pr0grammer: You'd have to do: `Object[][] subArray = (Object[][])docArray[3][0];` Then you could access `subArray` as an `Object[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

since `docArray[3]` is also an array, you can do....

`docArray[3] = new string[4]; //4 for example`

If memory serves correctly, this is called a jagged array.

Comment: But will that work for my purposes if I want the new array to be a multi dimensional array as well (same as the previous array)?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the following syntax:

```
String[][] s2d = new String[3][]; // creates a 2-Dimensional Array with 3 rows (or columns, depending on how you index/address
s2d[0] = new String[4] // creates a new 1-Dimensional Array with 4 columns (at row 0)
s2d[1] = new String[26] // creates a new 1-Dimensional Array with 26 columns (at row 1)
s2d[0][0] = "This is a cell at row 0, column 0"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is exactly what I am looking for, but I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key concept here is that no matter how you declare it, in Java, an array of anything is simply a normal object, defined as a series of elements of a given type, and therefore arrays of objects can contain other arrays.

There is no support in the JVM for multidimensional arrays to be handled any differently. So there are just two types of array:

The F[] array where F is a fundamental type (int, float, etc.)
The O[] array where O is any other type - including arrays ( O = F[], or O = O'[] )

So, for your question, you **can** make arrays of arrays, nothing will stop you. Just realize that you are simply accessing one dimensional arrays of object references.

The syntax ((array[i][j])[m][n])  is no different to (((((array[a])[b]))[c])[d])

From reading your question and earlier answers, I would offer the following advice: stay as strongly typed as possible, because you can only discard typing information as you delve deeper into your multi-dimensional array, you can never add it in. In a simple form you could represent your document using multiple simple types:

```
class Line extends ArrayList<String> {}

class Paragraph extends ArrayList<String> { public Line[] getLines(); } 
class TextParagraph extends Paragraph {}
class QuotedParagraph extends Paragraph {} 
class HeadingParagraph extends Paragraph {}

class Document { public static void main (String[] args) { 
  Paragraph[] multiDiDoc = new Paragraph[10]; 
  multiDiDoc[0] = new HeadingParagraph();
} }
```

Using an Object Model, you can preserve generality ('HeadingParagraph', 'QuotedParagraph', 'TextParagraph' types), and support specificity (arbitrary objects of type Object are not allowed).

If you stick with raw Objects, as your client application gets bigger you'll be wondering more and more often whether you are going to get hit a class cast exception.

Comment: SO looking at this answer, if I wanted to go this route. I would use class Line, class Paragraph, class HeadingParagraph, and of course class Document. These would be classes representative of elements I would of stored in the array. However, in the array I would of wanted to store pointers to sibling sections and child sections. So how would I create a class like that?

Comment: I would take getLines out of Paragraph, and add it to TextParagraph and make QuotedParagraph extend TextParagraph. Then you can use Paragraph as a generic element that could contain sibling sections or child sections. I'm not sure of your semantics behind sibling sections, but it kinda sounds like you want a list-type data structure rather than an array data structure. Depending on how brave you're feeling and how big your document is, you could look into skip lists. 
    **class Para { public Para prev(); public Para next(); public List<Para> children(); } Para docHead;**